# Azure TCP segmentation and HTTP chunks

Tags: azure, tcp

I have an Azure application that connects to a large installed base of devices. Everything has been working fine for years until today when everything has stopped working. What I think has happened is Azure is now segmenting the small (87 byte payload) message and this has exposed a bug in my TCP handler.

Does anyone know if there is a way of forcing Azure not to segment small TCP messages?

Follow up - I think this is because the HTTP message is 'chunked' and send as 2 TCP segments. There is a bug in my code that does not handle chunks which as only now surfaced.

Can I turn off chunking in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether there is a way to prevent a HTTP response from using HTTP [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), then perhaps, depending on the server-side APIs you are using.  Setting a Content-Length header usually suffices.

But I think your question is whether you can force Azure to buffer IP packets in a way that avoids the bug in your client, which is assuming that a single socket Read() will return a complete message.  In which case, no.  It may not even be within Azure's control, as any intermediate router could cause a delay in the delivery of packets, which, in turn, will cause the client's Read() to return a partial message.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here [Disable chunking in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966039/disable-chunking-in-asp-net-core)

In summary:

```
response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "identity";
response.Headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "identity";
```

This seems to disable unnecessary chunking. I have no idea how