# AspNet.Core returns 200 OK and invalid Json if there is an exception while iterating an IEnumerable (returned from controller)

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpresponse

It seems that AspNet.Core starts sending response that is `IEnumerable` right away without iterating over the whole collection. E.g.:

```
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData()
{
    IEnumerable<MyData> result = await _service.GetData();
    return Ok(result.Select(_mapper.MapMyDataToMyDataWeb));
}
```

Now there is an exception that happens during mapping of one of the elements, so I would assume a `500` response, but in reality what happens is that I get a `200` with only partial (and incorrect) Json.

I assume it's a feature and not a bug in `Asp.Net Core` that provides this behavior and it is additionally relatively easy to fix by calling e.g. `ToList()`, but I am wondering if there is some kind of flag that can prevent this situation from happening since it does not really make sense for e.g. API project and standard JSON response.

I was not able to find anything in documentation that describes this behavior and how to prevent it.

P.S. I have verified that calling `ToList()` fixes the issue and the response is 500 with correct exception (with `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`)

Comment: Your assumptions here are incorrect. A HTTP call is a single atomic unit. It doesn't stream the enumerable, it can't. The enumerator will be being enumerated in it's entirety before/as part of being serialised into JSON. If you getting an exception in you JSON then that's the serialisation process

Comment: @Liam agree, I bet the problem is in the mapper which stops mapping at some point and returns partial result which is converted to json and sent to client

Comment: Exception does happen not during serialization, but during enumeration. In this example it happens in the mapper, and it's a valid one, so I want the application to fail

Comment: @Liam I am not 100% sure if it's atomic or not, maybe it's .net core that starts constructing JSON array one element at a time and then return partial result (though that would be real strange), but the fact is that I get this partial result and I want to disallow it generally

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, I just wanted to point out that your barking up the wrong tree with with the *sending response that is IEnumerable right away without iterating over the whole collection*. This is not true

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy if that would be true I would get a correct JSON with only part of the data. While I get part of the data indeed the json is incorrect, it lacks the last `]` that closes the array

Comment: @canton7 `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` that's the header I get in the response, yes

Comment: Chunking is just a transport mechanism. Again as far as .Net is concerned, it's serialised the entire thing and offloaded it to a HTTP response to send to the client.

Comment: While I don't have enough knowledge to argue about how it theoretically can or can not work, I am 100% sure though is that I get incorrect JSON and want to prevent it globally instead of writing `ToList()` each time with possibility of forgetting it and client getting an invalid json instead of 500. Any ideas on how to prevent it? I assume that this is because it starts responding stream, and that's why it is happening. If there are other reasons for it, it does not change the fact unfortunately

Comment: Seems like `IHttpBufferingFeature.DisableResponseBuffering()` might be the way to go? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163755/1086121 . Also the answer using middleware in the same link.

Comment: That will have literally no effect.

Comment: `HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBufferingFeature>()` returns null for me at least in the request itself

Comment: Did you confirm that this does work if you `ToList()` it?

Comment: Yes, with `ToList()` I get an expected 500. I have added it to the question

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of the 500?

Comment: Ah, looks like that's only set by `ResponseCompressionMiddleware`? The middleware solution in the same link should work, I think? The other option of course is to subclass `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` and introduce buffering there.

Comment: @UncleDave There is nothing special with the stacktrace, I just see my Decimal.Parse exception that causes all this, exception just bubbles up to the top and gets converted to a 500. Is there anything specific you were thinking to see in there?

Comment: I was hoping to see some result executors running, but you're right it wouldn't help, as your exception will be coming from the controller before it even hits an executor.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is happening :)

Comment: @canton7 Yes, this actually prevents partial JSON from happening and returns 500, though a broken one (it's not intercepted by DevMiddleware e.g.) and body is just empty. I hope there is some better option available from the framework itself rather that adding this DeChunk middleware. Thanks for help anyway :) I can try to raise an issue in the aspnet core on github and see what the developers can say about it

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't play nicely with other middleware - I expect that's solvable. If you open an issue, please link it here - I'm curious!

Comment: I am pretty sure it's the order of the middlewares or something like that. Exception middleware most likely kicks in after DeChunk, but I'd rather use ToList I think, this DeChunk middleware is rather obscure. We'll see if someone comes with a better solution perhaps?

Comment: A neater solution than the middleware, I think, would be to subclass [NewtonsoftJsonResponseFormatter](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.cs), and override `WriteResponseBodyAsync` with a similar implementation, but pass a `new StringWriter()` to `CreateJsonWriter`, and then copy the contents of that `StringWriter` to `writer`. Then set it in `options.OutputFormatters`. That at least only applies to json responses, and not to all responses.

Comment: If you are getting a 200 then you are getting everything that was sent.  Chunk has nothing to do with issue because if chunk was used and entire message was not received you would get the next chunk message.  The issue is with sending side.  It looks like you are using multiple task and have to wait for all tasks to complete before sending.  You cannot start sending http with partial data.  You have to wait until you have all the data before sending.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete

Comment: @jdweng, yes that's what ToList() will achieve, I wanted though to make MVC itself do that for all controllers

Comment: Did you read the link I provided?

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure what you are pointing at and I have now found what is going on, you can check my answer. It has to do with how asp.net core behaves (by design). Thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this is actually "by design", this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5083) was raised few times on Asp.Net Core github repository.

What happens is that header with 200 is already sent, while the body is not. While I would think that enumeration must proceed before sending headers, asp.net team says it will use more resources on the server and that's why it is like that.

Here is a quote:

> It is very likely the case that your exception is thrown while writing
>   to the body, after headers have already been sent to the client, so
>   there's no take-backs on the 200 that was already sent as part of the
>   response. The client will see an error because the body will come back
>   as incomplete.
>
> If you want to deterministically report a 500 when this happens you'll
>   need to either:
>
> - Buffer your IEnumerable as part of the action (.ToList())
> - Buffer the response body -https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering
>     Obviously both of these things require more server-side resources,
>     which is why we don't have this kind of behavior by default.

I can confirm that this solution worked:

1. Reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering` package
2. Write `app.UseResponseBuffering()` before `app.UseMvc()`

Comment: Looks like time has taken its toll on that link, sadly, although I can't find its new home

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering

Comment: That's archived - the separate repos got subsumed into the main AspNetCore repo, although `BufferingWriteStream` and `ResponseBufferingMiddleware` are nowhere to be found. Perhaps it was just abandoned.

Comment: The library exists, I have checked that it works and I assume that it is actually similar to this `DeChunkMiddleware` only provided by Microsoft out of the box. Version is 0.2.2 for some reason and the documentation is an empty stub...

Comment: It does exist, although where the source is I have no idea! Anyway thanks for posting your solution, of course do be aware this will affect things like streaming files.

Comment: Yeah, I might just go back to doing `ToList()` in the end, which I knew solves the issue right away :) Could not find source either, MS still has some room for improvement there. Version 0.2.2 and no updates in 2 years is a bit suspicious though...

Comment: An enumerable is a streamable type. There's scenarios where you'd actually *want* that, although it does carry the risk that an exception could occur mid-stream. As such, I don't find it likely that Microsoft will make any changes here, because it could break perfectly valid scenarios. Long and short, if you want to ensure the result can be materialized, then you should use an atomic type like `List<T>`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That's what I ended up doing, though I don't see a scenario where returning JSON as a stream makes sense? It will always be an invalid json in the process and you cannot parse the resulting json anyway until you get it all. Though of course you can manage to have some special parser that can read json while it's being produced (elements in the array). So while it makes sense for the webserver as a whole to have this behavior, a controller returning JSON probably should not do that by default or at least have a generic option to tweak it

Comment: I think you're confusing different things. IEnumerable is streamable, and being generic, it can have all sorts of things in it, not just stuff that needs to be serialized. Indeed, when creating the response, the call to `JsonConvert` will actually force the enumerable to be materialized, because JSON itself cannot be streamed. However, by that point, the response has already started to be returned: namely, the status code and response headers.

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking: why does not Asp.Net iterate IEnumerable before sending headers so that it can produce 500 response if something goes wrong. There are definitely use cases when you want that, but I would think it's rather an exception than a rule. And as far as I figured out previous versions of WebApi did not have that behavior. So it seems more natural to that by default with a possibility of behavior that we see now. Though I doubt any changes would happen in reality anyway :)